# Mountpoint error in Ruby on Rails server using Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, capistrano3, s3fs

I am trying to automate app deployment using capistrano. I have almost completed all the tasks except s3 mounting and unmounting recipe.

Here is the recipe which I have written, it works in certain conditions and it does not in certain conditions. But the commands used in the recipe run if I manually login to the server and execute them myself.

```
desc "Mounting S3 for the first time"
    task :mounting_s3 do
        on %w(uat2_sub1 uat2_main), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do |host|
            as 'cc' do
                within '/var/www/test_cap/current' do
                    code_folder = "/var/www/test_cap/current"
                    path = "/var/www/test_cap/current/public/system"
                    unmount_path = "/var/www/test_cap/shared/public/system"

                    # check first if public/system exists
                    puts "** Checking if public/system folder exists on #{host}"
                    if test("[ -d #{path} ]")
                        puts "** public/system folder exists.."
                        puts "** Checking if S3 is mounted"
                        result = execute! "mountpoint #{path}"
                        puts "result #{result}"
                        if result.match('is a mountpoint') != nil
                            puts "** S3 is mounted at #{path} on #{host}"
                            puts "** unmounting s3 at #{unmount_path}"
                            execute! "fusermount -u #{unmount_path}"
                            puts "** s3 unmounted at #{unmount_path} on #{host}"
                        elsif result.match('is not a mountpoint') != nil
                            puts "** #{path} is not a mountpoint on #{host}"    
                        end 
                    else
                        puts "** public/system folder does not exists.."
                        puts "** Mounting S3"
                        execute! "cd #{code_folder} && s3fs cc-system-uat #{path}"  
                    end 
                end
            end
        end 
    end
```

I am able to **unmount S3** from capistrano using `fusermount -u` if I have mounted s3 from server myself.

Similarly I am able to **mount s3** from capistrano if I have unmounted s3 from server myself.

I am running all the commands as **cc user**. I still do not understand why I get the following error. In the logs it is visible that public/system is not a mount point but I am unable to move ahead from that point. As I want to store the result of **mountpoint "public/system"** in a variable and then execute different tasks.

```
** Invoke bundler:map_bins (first_time)
** Execute bundler:map_bins
** Invoke deploy:set_rails_env (first_time)
** Execute deploy:set_rails_env
** Invoke deploy:set_linked_dirs (first_time)
** Execute deploy:set_linked_dirs
** Invoke deploy:set_rails_env 
** Invoke deploy:mounting_s3 (first_time)
** Execute deploy:mounting_s3
** Checking if public/system folder exists on uat2_sub1
** public/system folder exists..
** Checking if S3 is mounted
00:00 deploy:mounting_s3
      01 mountpoint /var/www/test_cap/current/public/system
      01 /var/www/test_cap/current/public/system is not a mountpoint
cap aborted!
Exception while executing on host uat2_sub1: mountpoint /var/www/test_cap/current/public/system exit status: 1
mountpoint /var/www/test_cap/current/public/system stdout: /var/www/test_cap/current/public/system is not a mountpoint
mountpoint /var/www/test_cap/current/public/system stderr: Nothing written
/home/xyz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/sshkit-1.11.4/lib/sshkit/runners/sequential.rb:31:in `rescue in run_backend'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `raise_on_non_zero_exit: false` option fixed it. Actually capture throws error if there is no output.

```
result = capture "cd #{code_folder} && mountpoint public/system" , raise_on_non_zero_exit: false
```